# Most concise way of checking if a number falls betwen two other numbers?

Tags: c++, math, optimization

Suppose I have three numbers.  Two of them form a range between them.  The last number, I want to check to see if it falls within that range.  It's a simple caveat: the numbers that define the range's start and end, may be greater than or less than the other.  This is for a physics algorithm whose performance I'm working to improve, so I also want to avoid using conditional statements.

```
double inRange(double point, double rangeStart, double rangeEnd){
    // returns true if the 'point' lies within the range
    // the 'range' is every number between 'rangeStart' and 'rangeEnd'
    // rangeStart can be greater than or less than rangeEnd
    // conditional branches should be avoided


    return ?; // return values [0.0 - 1.0] are considered 'in range'
}
```

Is there a mathematical equation to accomplish this, without using condition logic?

edit:

The reason it returns a double instead of a bool, is because I need to know the ratio too; 0.0 is closest to one edge while 1.0 is closest to the other.

The original algorithm I have is this:

```
double inRange(double point, double rangeStart, double rangeEnd){
    if(rangeStart > rangeEnd){
         double temp = rangeStart;
         rangeStart = rangeEnd;
         rangeEnd = temp;
    }
    return (point - rangeStart) / (rangeEnd - rangeStart);
}
```

My profiler shows about 16% of the time the program is running, is spent in this function, with optimizations enabled.  It's called pretty frequently.  Not sure if the condition statement is entirely to blame, but I would like to try a function that doesn't have one and see.

Comment: Why does it return `double`?

Comment: Why do you think a conditional statement will slow it down?

Comment: Barry - I need to know the ratio within the range as well.  0.0 is closest to the rangeStart, and 1.0 is closest to the rangeEnd

Comment: So if the `rangeStart` is after `rangeEnd`, should it still return `true` if `point` is between them?

Comment: Why without condition logic? I assume because you think it's slow. In that case, you're conflating two issues: making the code correct, and making it correct and fast. If you don't have the first step, don't bother with the second. So which is it: do you want to know how to make this function return the correct value, or do you have an existing implementation you're going to show us that's too slow, with profiling results to back it up?

Comment: Judging by the fact you haven't even settled on the correct specifications, I'm going with the first...

Comment: @Clairvoire - so what should inRange(3.0, 5.0, 7.0) return?

Comment: I don't get how you want it to return "true" while the return type is double...

Comment: @GManNickG - Sorry, I left that out for brevity.  It's added now

Comment: @Barry - It would return -1.0

Comment: Aha, some people sure are loose with their downvotes

Comment: Double precision division is probably the slow part....

Comment: What is in a name? By many programmers (and managers), the importance of good identifier (function, variable) name is looked down. This is a classic example of that. The name `inRange()` causes the confusion because it expects a boolean outcome. If the function was named in line with what it is doing, say `ratio()` or `distanceRatio()` or  `percentile()`, then it could be lot clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to answer your specification "it should return zero when close to the start and 1 when close to the end", that you don't want conditionals, and that start and end might be swapped:

```
return (point-std::min(rangeStart, rangeEnd))/std::abs(rangeStart - rangeEnd);
```

Note that although I don't know about the particular STL implementation, `min` does not necessarily require conditionals to be implemented. For instance, min(a,b) = (a+b-abs(b-a))/2.

Comment: I just saw your edit : your code was very similar to this one.

Comment: I simplified the result by reducing the number of min, max calls. You don't need to call them in the denominator.

Comment: this is not efficient, as it contains a nasty division. Also `fabs` is not C++, use `std::abs`.

Comment: I don't know how much is changed from implementation to implementation but the ref says it uses the `<` operator in conjunction with an `if`. Plus I agree with Walter, you gave an answer less efficient than what he had, it just uses C++ "niceties."

Comment: the point is not debate about efficiency but to fulfill the OP's specifications (e.g., the division was already part of the problem). For instance, he might ultimately want to vectorize his code which wouldn't be great with conditionals (and my point is not to argue about what type of application the OP has in mind, or whether his application is good).

Comment: True, but the question was spawned from a concern OP had with profiling results. I'm not intending to "debate" efficiency, I'm just not convinced the percentage is going to get any better with this.

Comment: that may indeed be true ; but the OP just wanted to give it a try so why not, and predicting efficiency of micro optimizations is often hard or even counter intuitive. I upvoted his question for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

If the start is larger than the end, then swap those.